# Scala Spark SQLContext Program throwing array out of bound exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-2.10

I am new to Apache Spark. I am trying to create a schema and load data from hdfs. Below is my code:

```
// importing sqlcontext  
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.createSchemaRDD

//defining the schema
case class Author1(Author_Key: Long, Author_ID: Long, Author: String, First_Name: String, Last_Name: String, Middle_Name: String, Full_Name: String, Institution_Full_Name: String, Country: String, DIAS_ID: Int, R_ID: String)

val D_Authors1 = 
  sc.textFile("hdfs:///user/D_Authors.txt")
  .map(_.split("\\|"))
  .map(auth => Author1(auth(0).trim.toLong, auth(1).trim.toLong, auth(2), auth(3), auth(4), auth(5), auth(6), auth(7), auth(8), auth(9).trim.toInt, auth(10)))

//register the table
D_Authors1.registerAsTable("D_Authors1")
val auth = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM D_Authors1")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM D_Authors").collect().foreach(println)
```

When I am executing this code it throwing array out of bound exception. Below is the error:

```
    14/08/18 06:57:14 INFO Analyzer: Max iterations (2) reached for batch MultiInstanceRelations
    14/08/18 06:57:14 INFO Analyzer: Max iterations (2) reached for batch CaseInsensitiveAttributeReferences
    14/08/18 06:57:14 INFO SQLContext$$anon$1: Max iterations (2) reached for batch Add exchange
    14/08/18 06:57:14 INFO SQLContext$$anon$1: Max iterations (2) reached for batch Prepare Expressions
    14/08/18 06:57:14 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
    14/08/18 06:57:14 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at <console>:24
    14/08/18 06:57:14 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 5 (collect at <console>:24) with 2 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
    14/08/18 06:57:14 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 5(collect at <console>:24)
    14/08/18 06:57:14 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
    14/08/18 06:57:14 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
    14/08/18 06:57:14 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 5 (SchemaRDD[26] at RDD at SchemaRDD.scala:98
    == Query Plan ==
    ExistingRdd [Author_Key#22L,Author_ID#23L,Author#24,First_Name#25,Last_Name#26,Middle_Name#27,Full_Name#28,Institution_Full_Name#29,Country#30,DIAS_ID#31,R_ID#32], MapPartitionsRDD[23] at mapPartitions at basicOperators.scala:174), which has no missing parents
    14/08/18 06:57:14 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from Stage 5 (SchemaRDD[26] at RDD at SchemaRDD.scala:98
    == Query Plan ==
    ExistingRdd [Author_Key#22L,Author_ID#23L,Author#24,First_Name#25,Last_Name#26,Middle_Name#27,Full_Name#28,Institution_Full_Name#29,Country#30,DIAS_ID#31,R_ID#32], MapPartitionsRDD[23] at mapPartitions at basicOperators.scala:174)
    14/08/18 06:57:14 INFO YarnClientClusterScheduler: Adding task set 5.0 with 2 tasks
    14/08/18 06:57:14 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0:0 as TID 38 on executor 1: orf-bat.int..com (NODE_LOCAL)
    14/08/18 06:57:14 INFO TaskSetManager: Serialized task 5.0:0 as 4401 bytes in 1 ms
    14/08/18 06:57:15 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0:1 as TID 39 on executor 1: orf-bat.int..com (NODE_LOCAL)
    14/08/18 06:57:15 INFO TaskSetManager: Serialized task 5.0:1 as 4401 bytes in 0 ms
    14/08/18 06:57:15 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost TID 38 (task 5.0:0)
    14/08/18 06:57:15 WARN TaskSetManager: Loss was due to java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
            at $line39.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:27)
            at $line39.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:27)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$1.next(Iterator.scala:853)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$1.head(Iterator.scala:840)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExistingRdd$$anonfun$productToRowRdd$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:179)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExistingRdd$$anonfun$productToRowRdd$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:174)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:559)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:559)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD.compute(SchemaRDD.scala:110)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:111)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:51)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:187)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    14/08/18 06:57:15 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost TID 39 (task 5.0:1)
    14/08/18 06:57:15 WARN TaskSetManager: Loss was due to java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
            at $line39.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:27)
            at $line39.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:27)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$1.next(Iterator.scala:853)
            at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$1.head(Iterator.scala:840)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExistingRdd$$anonfun$productToRowRdd$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:179)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExistingRdd$$anonfun$productToRowRdd$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:174)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:559)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:559)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD.compute(SchemaRDD.scala:110)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:111)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:51)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:187)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Seems there may exist arrays generated by `map(_.split("\\|"))` containing less number of elements. Can you check that?

Answer (score 5):

Your problem has nothing to do with Spark.

1. Format your code correctly (I have corrected)
2. Don't mix camel & underscore naming - use underscore for SQL fields, use camel for Scala vals,
3. When you get an exception *read it* it usually tells you what you are doing wrong, in your case it's probably that some of the records in `hdfs:///user/D_Authors.txt` are not how you expect them
4. When you get an exception *debug it*, try actually catching the exception and printing out what the records are that fail to parse
5. `_.split("\\|")` ignores empty leading and trailing strings, use `_.split("\\|", -1)`
6. In Scala you don't need magic numbers that manually access elements of an array, it's ugly and more prone to error, use a pattern match ...

here is a simple example **which includes unusual record handling!**:

```
case class Author(author: String, authorAge: Int)

myData.map(_.split("\t", -1) match {
  case Array(author, authorAge) => Author(author, authorAge.toInt)
  case unexpectedArrayForm => 
    throw new RuntimeException("Record did not have correct number of fields: " +
      unexpectedArrayForm.mkString("\t"))
})
```

Now if you coded it like this, your exception would tell you straight away exactly what is wrong with your data.

One final point/concern; why are you using Spark SQL? Your data is in text form, are you trying to transform it into, say, parquet?  If not, why not just use the regular Scala API to perform your analysis, moreover it's type checked and compile checked, unlike SQL.

Comment: Why do we use map(_.split('\t',-1)) here ?? It actually solved my problem but I didn't get it why is it so ?? can anybody explain me in layman terms ?? Thanks